# facebook persistent menu with api.ai

Tags: facebook, nlp, dialogflow-es

i tried with custom webhook on my server for FB persistent menu and other features it works fine.
when i am using api.ai as webhook and for NLP understanding and Facebook bot as client interface then in that case how to use persistent menu.

Comment: Are you hosting your own bot?

Comment: @BcfAnt yes ! i am hosting my own server though that i want have menu driven options in facebook bot. i tried though api.ai->> intents->> QuickReplies section where i added menu driven response for pre define intents, but i want to add those through webhook response from my own server though api.ai for dynamic responses

Answer (score 0):

Set the persistent menu (don't forget to set your access token).

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "persistent_menu":[
    {
      "locale":"default",
      "composer_input_disabled":false,
      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "title":"Examples",
          "type":"nested",
          "call_to_actions":[
            {
              "type":"postback",
              "title":"Option 1",
              "payload":"OPTION_1"
            },
            {
              "type":"postback",
              "title":"Option 2",
              "payload":"OPTION_2"
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          "type":"postback",
          "title":"Share Bot",
          "payload":"SHARE"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>"`

In your bot code, double check that your POST webhook deals with the event.postback. Then check the payload of the postback to action the menu request.

```
if(event.postback.payload == "OPTION_1") {
    // Option 1 bot action
}
if(event.postback.payload == "OPTION_2") {
    // Option 2 bot action
}
if(event.postback.payload == "SHARE") {
    // Share bot action
}
```